# Django not running from Docker image, cant access

Tags: python, django, docker, dockerfile, google-compute-engine

My `Dockerfile` is:

```
FROM python:3.5
RUN apt-get update 
USER root
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
WORKDIR /app/etalentNET
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "makemigrations"]
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "migrate"]
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

My `docker-compose.yaml` is:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: sqlite3
  web:
    build:
      image: demo:latest
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
     depends_on:
      - db
```

When I run `docker run -p 8000:8000 demo` it doesn't do anything.

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE   COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS
4829d420c560   demo   "python manage.py ru…"    9 minutes ago   Exited (0)
```

But when I run `docker run -p 8000:8000 -it demo bash` and then there `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` the servers start running (but can't access it via `<host_ip>:8000`. I don't know why).

I'm running in a Google Cloud Compute Engine virtual machine with `Ubuntu 16.04`, and `Django-2.0.6`.

Comment: What about your docker-compose.yml file? Have you read it https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/#define-the-project-components?

Comment: @AndrésQuiroga There I added it to the question

Comment: you are forwarding the host ip of 8002 to 8000 of docker. Maybe thats the issue. Try accessing 8002 on host machine or change it to 8000.

Comment: @ChetanGanji Do the change and doesnt change anything

Comment: Are you running this in a Google Cloud Compute Engine virtual machine instance? Or are you doing this in Google App Engine with a custom runtime?

Comment: @PhilippSh im trying the first one

Comment: Can you check the container logs to see what happened (docker logs CONTAINER)? The status implies the container ran it's course and closed. Likely something within the script is either failing or completing instead of continuously running.

Answer (score 0):

Put `allowed_hosts='*'` in settings.py